# Equivalence relation in a category

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to work through the definition of a Heyting pretopos, and one part says that

> For any equivalence relation $R\rightrightarrows X$ there exists some arrow $X\to Y$ such that $R\rightrightarrows X\to Y$ is exact.

But I can't really find a discussion of what an equivalence relation in a category is on the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivalence+relation) or in Awodey, only a discussion of the fact that coequalizers in **Set** are quotients by minimal equivalence relations generated by equality for the functions we're coequalizing. My question is:

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with finite limits. What is the correct internal notion of an equivalence relation on $X\in{\bf Ob}_\mathcal{C}$?

It seems obvious that an equivalence relation $R$ on $X$ should be a subobject of $X\times X$ such that the diagonal of $X\times X$ (viewed as the kernel pair of $1_X$) is a subobject of $R$ (reflexiveness), and if we realize this internalization in **Set** we should get back a the classical definition of equivalence relations, but it's not really clear to me what internal properties an equivalence relation should have besides the above to yield symmetry (something about interchanging coordinates?) and transitivity.

Any assistance or hints are appreciated.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/congruence

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Exactly what I was looking for, much appreciated..